# Assigning the selected values of checkboxlist items to listbox

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

I am developing a small business application to display the report retrieved from database and I have a checkboxlist consisting of four checkboxes, also a combobox. Now, I am retrieving the required info from database to combobox with 4 items while on page load, which is ok. Not only this, but also retrieving the checkboxlist DataTextField on the checkboxes from database,which is also ok.

As for my question on this issue, lets assume that I have a combobox with 2 items, name and age and also 4 checkboxes named with George, Michael, 23, 33.

Here, 23 and 33 belong to Name(combobox.selectedindex[0]) items of checkboxes and George, Michael belong to the Age item of combobox. Then, I want to display on the listbox that when clicking Name item of combobox, checkboxes of Michael and George come to the screen as checked automatically and when clicking the button, those selected values of checkboxes are displayed on the listbox for both nMme and Age items of combobox in the same logic.

I tried to make this several times, but fail to achieve this goal. How to do this, can you please lead the way to me on my this issue?
Thank a a lot for replying.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to add Name or Age as checkBoxListItem.Tag to the corresponding values and everytime you change selection in the combobox you iterate through all the checkBoxItems and chack the ones with the corresponding tag and uncheck the others.